# FileSystemWatcher with the console application

Tags: c#, file-watcher

To send bulk email in my web application I am using filewatcher to send the application.

I have planned to write filewatcher with the console application instead of windows service or scheduler.

I have copied the executable file shortcut in the following path.

%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/948088/how-to-add-exe-to-start-menu-in-windows-10

After run the executable file the file watcher is not watched always.
After searching some sites, i have found that we need to add the code

```
new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
```

**Is this the right method to add in the executable file and to watch the folder?**

**After run the console application (without above code) is the file won't be watched always?**

What will be the right method to use the file watcher?

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["documentPath"];
watcher.Path = filePath;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName; 
watcher.Filter = "*.*";
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

Comment: Have you made your program wait in the `MAIN` method after started watching?

Comment: I am asking the doubt here what will be the correct method to be watched. 
Yes I have made to wait in the main method.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct but you should be aware of that it only watches the files are in the `root` , **not** the file are in the in `sub-folders`.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that and add that condition. Here I have two questions. So I need to add the code [new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne(); ] to be watched always..  I want to know the reason that why we should watch only the rootfolder not the subfolder?.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since it's a `Console Application` you need to write a code in the `Main` method to wait and not to close immediately after running codes.

```
static void Main()
{
   FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
   string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["documentPath"];
   watcher.Path = filePath;
   watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
   watcher.Filter = "*.*";
   watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);


   // wait - not to end
   new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
}
```

Your code only tracks changes in the `root` folder, ***if you wanted to watch the subfolders*** you need to set `IncludeSubdirectories=true` for your watcher object.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
   string filePath = @"d:\watchDir";
   watcher.Path = filePath;
   watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
   watcher.Filter = "*.*";

   // will track changes in sub-folders as well
   watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

   watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

   new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
}
```

You must also be aware of buffer overflow. [FROM MSDN FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6)

> The Windows operating system notifies your component of file changes
>   in a buffer created by the FileSystemWatcher. **If there are many**
>   **changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow**. This causes the
>   component to losing track of changes in the directory, and it will only
>   provide the blanket notification. Increasing the size of the buffer with
>   the InternalBufferSize property is expensive, as it comes from
>   non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so keep the
>   buffer as small yet large enough to not miss any file change events.
>   To avoid a buffer overflow, use the NotifyFilter and
>   IncludeSubdirectories properties so you can filter out unwanted change
>   notifications.

Comment: I am going to check only xml file which is only added to the specific folder (This will occur occasionally) and I have used NotifyFilter to know only for the filename and I am going to check only for the root folder. So will this yield buffer overflow.

Comment: @JeevaJsb How often does the file change? if it's so frequent then you've got to increase the `InternalBufferSize` as I mentioned above.